# vlookup in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes
I want to check if a column from first dataframe contains values that are in the column of second dataframe, and if it does, create a column and add 1 to the row where it contains a value from first column
first df:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | apple |
| Second | orange |
| third | banana |
| fourth | tea |

desired output in second df
second df:

| A header | Another header | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | sheet | 0 |
| Second | chair | 0 |
| third | apple | 1 |
| fourth | orange | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and convert boolean to `1/0` values by casting:

```
df2['match'] = df2['Another header'].isin(df1['Another header']).astype(int)
```

Or by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df2['match'] = np.where(df2['Another header'].isin(df1['Another header']), 1, 0)
```